# how to either filter or trim white space in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Can anyone help?

I need a way to remove the white space in the URL of my MVC 2 application

if the URL appear this way I want to remove the white space before the last slash. At the moment this is not working 
**http://www.helpfulmove.co.uk/Removal_companies_In/London /**

but I remove the space before last slash it works fine

http://www.helpfulmove.co.uk/Removal_companies_In/London/

Here is my routing settings

```
routes.MapRoute("Removals_CompaniesPage",
"Removal_Companies_In/{Removal_Companies_In}/{page}/",
new { controller = "Removal_Companies_In", action = "OutputContent", Removal_Companies_In="uk", page = "index" } );
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How does the space end up in the url?

Comment: It looks like something wired is happening with the crawlers. I get the errors from Googlebot. I have checked the site map no white space

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the issue is that the url is created incorrectly.

Thus I would focus on fixing this and not the symptom.

Comment: But the problem is still there

Comment: @Terry when you say it appears this way, could you tell me what is creating this url?